# invalid prop source supplied to image React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native. I have a list of image files stored in json format and would like to display them in a flatlist, but am getting the following warning

[image: error]

Here is my json

```js
[{"eventDate": "Tuesday", "eventImage": "require('./youth.png')", "eventTime": "11am - 1pm", "id": "2", "name": "Food Band"}, {"eventDate": "Friday", "eventImage": "require('./youth.png')", "eventTime": "7:30pm", "id": "3", "name": "Youth"}]
```

Here is my code.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true, 
      imageHolder: ''
      
    }
  }
  webCall= () => {
       fetch('http://5e26eb00.ngrok.io/events.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }, 
      }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson,
        imageHolder: responseJson[0].eventImage
      }, () => {
      });
      console.log(responseJson);
    }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  }
   componentDidMount(){
 
    this.webCall();
   
   }
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading){
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
   <FlatList
   
    data={ this.state.dataSource }
    
    ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}

    renderItem={({item}) => 
    
        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 30, paddingLeft: 10}}>

          <Image source={item.eventImage}

              style={{ width: 100, height: 100, paddingBottom: 10 }}
            />
        
        <View>
              <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer}>{item.name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.SermonByText}>{item.eventDate} - {item.eventTime}</Text>
          </View>

        </View>
    
      }

    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    
    />

 </View>
);
}
```

My images are stored locally on my computer and I am using Xcode to run an iOS simulator. I can't understand why my images won't display or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: are you importing Image from react-native?

Comment: `require('./youth.png')` is JavaScript code.  It's not going to actually execute if run from a string.

Comment: yes I am importing it

Comment: then how do I get it to work?

Comment: Where are the images that you are trying to load?  Are they part of your application's source or are they on an image server some where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `source` of the `<Image>` to a String with the value of `"require('./youth.png')"`.  This isn't going to execute the way you think it is.  If you need to `require`, you **have** to execute that as part of your actual program due to the way React Native bundles static assets.

If that value is coming from some service, it won't work.  If this is some JSON file or Object that you define elsewhere in your program, you need to execute the `require` explicitly.

```
const img = require('./youth.png');
// or
import img from './youth.png';

<Image source={img} />
```

---

If your JSON is coming from some service, then you need another service to host the images.  React Native will only bundle assets that it knows about and can determine at "compile" time.

Comment: all I have to do now is to work out where to host my images